# IIS error Request not supported: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot' on Windows server 2019

Tags: iis, windows-server-2019

I have IIS setup on a Windows server 2019 which was working fine since more than a year. However, all of sudden I am getting an error "Request not supported: C:\inetpub\wwwroot" when I type localhost in a browser on the server.

I checked the web.config file of IIS and other settings in IIS but could not figure out the issue. The directory C:\inetpub\wwwroot exists and my Default website in IIS is linked to this directory.

Does anyone has an idea what is causing the issue?

Comment: Please edit the question to include a full screen shot of that error in your browser tab.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, have you changed some settings of iis? or update some content in Windows server 2019?

Comment: "Request not supported: C:\inetpub\wwwroot" this is the full error message that I see in the browser.

Comment: These error messages alone will not solve your problem, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.